# mocha api test - PUT route

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I have the following test in mocha that yields "Uncaught AssertionError: undefined == 'Ernest'.  I had a sneaking suspicion that the test was actually finding the song instance that is created in the top of the test, and I believe this proves it.  That being said, I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is an api written for a MEAN stack app, with mongoose as the ODM

test.js

```
it('can save a song', function(done) {
        Song.create({ title: 'saveASong' }, function(error, doc) {
            assert.ifError(error);
            var url = URL_ROOT + '/create/song/saveASong';
            superagent.
                put(url).
                send({
                    title: 'saveASong',
                    createdBy: 'Ernest'
                }).
                end(function(error, res) {
                    assert.ifError(error);
                    assert.equal(res.status, status.OK);
                    Song.findOne({}, function(error, song) {
                        assert.ifError(error);
                        assert.equal(song.title, 'saveASong');
                        assert.equal(song.createdBy, 'Ernest');
                        done();
                    });
                });
        });     
    });
```

my route:

```
//PUT (save/update) song from the create view
    api.put('/create/song/:title', wagner.invoke(function(Song) {
        return function(req, res) {
            Song.findOne({ title: req.params.title}, function(error, song) {
                if(error) {
                    return res.
                        status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
                        json({ error: error.toString() });
                }
                song.save(function(error, song) {
                    if(error) {
                        return res.
                            status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
                            json({ error: error.toString() });
                    }
                    return res.json({ song: song });
                });
            });         
        };
    }));
```

UPDATE: I put in a console.log(res.body) right after the "end", and it did not include the "createdBy: Ernest" k/v pair.  So I tried to alter the object being sent to another k/v pair (that is from schema, of course) and still nothing persisted.  I do not receive any errors if I comment out the "assert.equal...'Ernest'" line.

My latest version of PUT route:

```
api.put('/create/song/:title', wagner.invoke(function(Song) {
        return function(req, res) {
            Song.findOneAndUpdate({ title: req.params.title}, req.body ,{ new: true }, function(error, song) {

                if(error) {
                    return res.
                    status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
                    json({ error: error.toString() });
                }

                return res.json({ song: song });
                });
        };          
    }));
```

Comment: Please state what ORM and DBMS you're using. Note that the underlying database might not guarantee immediate consistency.

Comment: sorry, good point.  mongoose on mongodb.

Comment: I don't see you actually updating the document (using `req.body`) in the route handler.

Comment: @robertklep I placed the following above "song.save".... 'song = req.body;'.  mocha test fails, "song.save is not a function"

Comment: `song = req.body` makes the `song` variable point to `req.body`, which is just a plain object and not a Mongoose document instance. I think you want to use [`Song.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) instead of `Song.find()/.save()`.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you that seems logical.  After reading through the docs and some examples I am unsure what to put as my "update" parameter..req.body?  I'll will edit the post to show my present PUT route

Comment: `req.body` seems like the logical choice. Does it work? You have to be aware that any properties that you're trying to set need to be defined in the Mongoose schema, otherwise Mongoose won't pick them up.

Comment: yep, that worked, thanks for your help @robertklep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following api route

```
api.put('/create/song/:title', wagner.invoke(function(Song) {
        return function(req, res) {
            Song.findOneAndUpdate({ title: req.params.title}, req.body ,{ new: true }, function(error, song) {

                if(error) {
                    return res.
                    status(status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
                    json({ error: error.toString() });
                }

                return res.json({ song: song });
                });
        };          
    }));
```

passes the following mocha test

```
it('can save a song', function(done) {
        Song.create({ title: 'saveASong' }, function(error, doc) {
            assert.ifError(error);
            var url = URL_ROOT + '/create/song/saveASong';
            superagent.
                put(url).
                send({
                    sections:[{ name: 'intro', timeSig: 140 }]
                }).
                end(function(error, res) {
                    assert.ifError(error);
                    assert.equal(res.status, status.OK);
                    console.log(res.body);
                    Song.findOne({}, function(error, song) {
                        assert.ifError(error);
                        assert.equal(song.title, 'saveASong');
                        //console.log(song);
                        assert.equal(song.sections[0].name, 'intro');
                        done();
                    });
                });
        });     
    });
```